# Why the following space is homeomorphic to the Klein Bottle?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, klein-bottle

Why the following space is homeomorphic to the Klein Bottle?

$$\Bbb R^2/ \Gamma,\qquad \Gamma:=<\alpha,\beta>$$
where 
$$\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0& 1/2\\
0 & -1 & 1/2\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \beta=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0& 0\\
0 & 1 & 1/2\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

**Edit:** This is exercise 2.3 (page 6) of Leonard S. Charlap's book:  [Bieberbach Groups and Flat Manifolds](https://books.google.com/books?id=h3frBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR1&dq=Bieberbach%20Groups%20and%20Flat%20Manifolds&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Perhaps you could indicate what your definition of the Klein bottle is (the answer will be slightly different depending on your precise definition) ? Also, what does $\mathbb R^2/\Gamma$ mean, since $\Gamma $ is a subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb R)$ ?

Comment: @Max The matrices seem to be matrix representations of affine transformations. The blocks $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ would represent linear transformations, while $$\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1/2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1/2\end{bmatrix}$$ would represent translations.